# How to find a line after or before a specific string in Python 3 using regex?

Tags: python, regex

How to find a line before or after a particular string in python3 using regex? i am reading the content from text file pls help me

file.txt

```
my name is dharshini
my mom name is chandra
my dad name is uday
my anniversay is on 04/01/1997
```

```py
import re

with open('file.txt','r') as f:
input_file = f.readlines()

for line in input_file :
 find_line = re.findall(r'(mom)', line)
 print(next-1(line))
 print(next(line))
 print(next(line))
```

Expected Output:

```
my name is dharshini
my dad name is uday
my anniversay is on 04/01/1997
```

Comment: Is the paragraph variable a string or list ?

Comment: i made some changes pls see the code once again

Comment: this will be the same results as in my code becuse readlines use a list

Comment: You should edit your title "how to find a line after AND before a specific string in python3 using regex?"

Answer (score 4):

Try using `enumerate`, `enumerate` get's the index while looping, so i get the index and get rest of the values by indexing and slicing:

```
for i,line in enumerate(paragraph):
    if 'mom' in line:
        print(paragraph[:i])
        print(paragraph[i:])
```

**Edit:**

```
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    input_file = f.readlines()
    for i,line in enumerate(input_file):
        line=line.rstrip()
        if 'mom' in line:
            print(paragraph[:i])
            print(paragraph[i:])
```

Comment: @Python_beginner Don't forget to up-vote and accept if it works :-)

Comment: why you not explain what it doing. then he will learn something from this

Comment: @Matthijs990 Better?

Comment: yeah but if i was you i will use # comments

Comment: then you explain it in the line it self

Comment: @Matthijs990 Usually users don't do that, that isn't eye catching and it is not part of the code

Comment: good point it is just how i work if you do it on a other way it is fine just if you explain it is good

Comment: i have made some changes pls see the code once again

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import re

paragraph = ["my name is dharshini", "my mom name is chandra", "my dad name is uday" ,  "my anniversay is on 04/01/1997" ]
#set a flag for later
print_next = False
for line in paragraph:
 find_line = re.findall(r'(mom)', line)
 #if mom is found dad will be next
 if print_next:
     print(line)
     print_next = False
 #if mom is found
 if len(find_line) > 0:
     print(line)
     print_next = True
```

Comment: i have made some changes pls see the code once again